# XLookup Returning #N/A

Tags: excel, vba, xlookup

I am writing a script to convert a User Input date to a format that is used elsewhere in the Workbook. Two values are simple equations, but another two require a custom format used in this sheet.

I have tried with the lookup_value in Date & General formats. No matter what, I just receive the #N/A value. So far, I have reached this:

```
Dim src_yr_mess, src_mo_mess, src_dy_mess, src_title, Default
Dim src_yr_val As Integer, src_yr_short As String
Dim src_mo_num, src_mo_name As String
Dim src_dy_val As Integer, src_dy_short As String

    'The following opens a series of dialogue boxes requesting input from the user.
    src_yr_mess = "Please enter the year being queried. (i.e. 2023)"
    src_mo_mess = "Please enter the month being queried. (i.e. 01)"
    src_dy_mess = "Please enter the day (preceding Friday) being queried. (i.e. 13)"
    src_title = "Query Parameters"
    Default = ""
    
    src_yr_val = InputBox(src_yr_mess, src_title, Default)
    src_mo_num = InputBox(src_mo_mess, src_title, Default)
    src_dy_val = InputBox(src_dy_mess, src_title, Default)

...

Dim cur_wk As Date
Dim prv_wk As Date
Dim cur_wk_long
Dim prv_wk_long

cur_wk = DateValue(src_mo_num & "/" & src_dy_val)
prv_wk = DateValue(src_mo_num & "/" & src_dy_val) - 7
cur_wk_long = Application.XLookup(cur_wk, Sheets("week number").Range("C2:C53"), Sheets("week number").Range("D2:D53"))
prv_wk_long = Application.XLookup(prv_wk, Sheets("week number").Range("C2:C53"), Sheets("week number").Range("D2:D53"))
```

My table looks like this:

Col B/C
Data: `12/31/2022`
Format: Custom

Col D
Data: `=C2`
Format: General

Col E
Data: `=CONCATENATE(TEXT(B2,"m/dd")," to ",(TEXT(C2,"m/dd")))`
Format: General

[image: LookUp Table]

Comment: Even if your format is Custom to just mm/dd., you need the year on the XLookUp. Add year to cur_wk/prv_wk and it may work. Also this can all be done with a formula, any reason you prefer VBA?

Comment: Adding the src_yr_val did not solve the issue. The reason I am using VBA is because this is part of a larger Macro being tied to a single button. There is more within the "..." as well as proceeding the provided code.

Comment: I'd advise using `DateSerial` over `DateValue`. You could also try entering those lines in the Immediate window to test output. Try something like `?cur_wk = Range("B2").Value` where you know it should be working. Then look at those values separately to see why it isn't matching.